# Forwarding to firewalled web server over reverse SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a server running NGINX on local port 80 within my corporate NAT. From any remote box, I am able to setup a reverse SSH connection and connect to the firewalled box on port 22.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
user@corp:~$ ssh -R 4000:localhost:22 me@remote.box
```

and from the remote box,

```
me@remote:~$ ssh user@localhost -p 4000
```

Now this is fine and dandy, and works perfectly fine. How can I map arbitrary services on arbitrary ports on the corporate box to my remote box? Trying port 80 instead of 22 doesn't appear to work.

The corp network has typical mail and HTTP/S ports open.

My remote box runs Debian 6 and the corporate box runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to bypass controls put in place by your employer's IT department. If that's the case, the intent of your question violates the [faq], otherwise you might want to clarify why you're attempting this implementation as opposed to something more direct like a DMZ.

Answer (score 0):

Check, that port 80 is not in use by other process on your corporate box and if it is really accessible from outside NAT.

Port 80 may be tricky, because some web interfaces on routers can be using port 80 for remote configuration so you wont be able to use it without additional configuration.